# Touch event not making spritenode reset its size when moved off location of node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch

I have a sprite node in game that when touched makes an action of the node being pressed and when the touches began event is called and then goes back to the normal size when the touches ended event is called. my problem is when i press down on the node and then move my finger outside of the node it doesn't go back to its original size after I take my finger off the screen.

I tried using multiple things in the touches moved section of the code to try and get it to go back to its original size after i've moved my finger outside of the node while holding the touch down but it didn't work. My code is below

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    let node = self.atPoint(touch.location(in: self))
    let pushdown = SKAction.scale(to: 0.8, duration: 0.1)

    if node == mainMenu.settingsButton {
        node.run(pushdown)

    } else if node == mainMenu.viewMapButton {
        node.run(pushdown)

    }else if node == mainMenu.shopButton {
        node.run(pushdown)
    }

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    var location: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
    let node: SKNode = atPoint(location)
    let pushUp = SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.2)

    if node != mainMenu.settingsButton {
        //node.run(pushUp)

    } else if touch.phase == .moved || touch.phase == .cancelled {

        node.run(pushUp)

    }

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    let node = self.atPoint(touch.location(in: self))
    let pushUp = SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.2)

    if node == mainMenu.settingsButton {
        node.run(pushUp)
        //Run Sound Here

        let scene = SettingsMenu(fileNamed:"SettingsMenu")
        scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        //scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.5)
        self.scene?.view?.presentScene(scene!, transition: transition)

    } else if node == mainMenu.viewMapButton {
        node.run(pushUp)
    }
}
```

**How can i get it to go back to the original size after i've moved my finger outside of the nodes location while holding the touch down?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded you are referring always the current node at point. `let node = self.atPoint(touch.location(in: self))`
Why not to keep a reference to the initial node which was detected in touchesBegan to scale it back if the current node atPoint is not equal to the initial one. I assume this would solve your issue.

EDIT:

To capture the node on first touch ...

```
private var currentTouchedNode : SKNode?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
        currentTouchedNode = self.atPoint(touch.location(in: self))
        let pushdown = SKAction.scale(to: 0.8, duration: 0.1)

        if currentTouchedNode == mainMenu.settingsButton {
            currentTouchedNode.run(pushdown)

        } else if currentTouchedNode == mainMenu.viewMapButton {
            currentTouchedNode.run(pushdown)

        }else if currentTouchedNode == mainMenu.shopButton {
            currentTouchedNode.run(pushdown)
        }

    }
```

In touchesMoved, touchesEnded you would compare on if the current node is equal currentTouchedNode and resize it if needed

Comment: Could provide a rough example?

Comment: @Astrum I am glad that I was able to help. Have a great day.